# Overriding properties of public field

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a custom button with a textfield inside:

```
package com.company.utils.ui
{
    import flash.display.Shape;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;

    public class CustomButton extends Sprite
    {
        public var label:TextField;
```

label is public because I want to do this:

```
var playButton:CustomButton = new CustomButton();
playButton.label.embedFonts = true;
playButton.label.antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;
playButton.label.sharpness = 1;
playButton.label.thickness = 25;
playButton.label.gridFitType = GridFitType.PIXEL;
playButton.label.defaultTextFormat = customTextFormat;
```

But my problem is that I need to do something else (call a private customButton private method) when I assign a text to label.

```
playButton.label.text = "myText";
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You coud create your own custom `TextField` class then override the `text` property so that when you assign a value you can incorparate some extra functionality. Then in you `CustomButton` class, your label property can be an instance of that custom `TextField` class. I made the following example to demonstrate this:

Main.as{document class):

```
package 
{
    import com.flashdevelopprojects.display.CustomButton;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        }// end function

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            var customButton:CustomButton = new CustomButton();
            customButton.label.text = "supercalifragilisticexpialidocious";
            trace(customButton.label.text); // supercalif...

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package
```

CustomButton.as:

```
package com.flashdevelopprojects.display 
{
    import com.flashdevelopprojects.text.CustomTextField;
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class CustomButton extends Sprite 
    {
        public var label:CustomTextField;

        public function CustomButton() 
        {
            init();

        }// end function

        private function init():void
        {
            label = new CustomTextField();

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package
```

CustomTextField.as:

```
package com.flashdevelopprojects.text 
{
    import flash.text.TextField;

    public class CustomTextField extends TextField
    {
        override public function get text():String { return super.text }
        override public function set text(text:String):void { super.text = truncate(text) }

        private function truncate(text:String):String
        {
            return (text.length > 10) ? text.substring(0, 10) + "..." : text;

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end class
```

In this example when assigning a string value to the `label` object's `text` property, the private method `truncate()` is called and is parse that string value. If the string value's length is above 10 then a string of the original string value is returned that is truncated. Then the truncated string is assigned to the `super.text` property.

Now when you trace the `label` object's `text` property, you get the truncated string and not the original string.

Answer (score 1):

it would be better to not expose the label directly but create getter/setter functions for properties of the label -> [Encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29).

pseudocode:

```
CustomButton
{
  private var label:TextField;

  public function CustomButton()
  {
     label = new TextField();
  }

  public function setLabelSharpness(sharp:int):void
  {
     label.sharpness = sharp;
  }
}
```

and you could add another function for setText(txt:String) which truncates the txt before setting the text property of the label.

```
public function setText(txt:String):void
{
  _originalText = txt;
  txt = (txt.length > 10) ? txt.substring(0, 10) + "..." : txt;
  label.text = txt;
}

public function getText():String
{
  return label.text;
}

public function getOriginalText():String
{
  return _originalText;
}
```

something like this ....
cheers

Comment: Please don't copy the truncation from my answer `(txt.length > 10) ? txt.substring(0, 10) + "..." : txt` or at the very least mention it is from my answer.

Comment: sry, thought i copied it from the original question. but wasn't really important for the answer, just some code to demonstrate my point.